# adding two very large numbers

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add two numbers of any length in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748846/how-to-add-two-numbers-of-any-length-in-java)

can anyone help me with this?

what i need to do is to add a very large number that a calculator doesn't hold.

this is the code i have though it can only hold a number until 2147483647.. any number higher than that i get the error message stating "integer number too large"

can anyone tell me how can i use a larger number?

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class AddTwoBigNumbers{
  public static void main() {
  BigDecimal num1, num2;
  num1 = new BigDecimal(2147483647);
  num2 = new BigDecimal(2147483647);
  Sum(num1, num2);
  }

  public static void Sum(BigDecimal val1, BigDecimal val2){
  BigDecimal sum = val1.add(val2);
  System.out.println("Sum of two BigDecimal numbers: "+ sum);
  }
}
```

Comment: Following links may help you...

[A similar question][1]
[Another Similar Question][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748846/how-to-add-two-numbers-of-any-length-in-java
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318068/very-large-numbers-in-java-without-using-java-math-biginteger

Comment: [Check this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318068/very-large-numbers-in-java-without-using-java-math-biginteger

Comment: To add these two number together all you need is a `long`.  Sometimes it is best to use the simplest solution for your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

---

**[edit]** To pass a number larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to the constructor, use a `long`:

```
new BigInteger(9876543210L)
```

If you need a number larger than a `long` can hold, you'll need to find some other way of constructing it (like passing it in as a string, or multiplying two `BigInteger`s).

Comment: This won't solve the problem, look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

When you construct your BigDecimal, you are doing it with an integer.  In Java, integers can only hold 2^31, so when you construct your BigDecimal that way, that's all it will allow.  The compiler will complain if you give it a larger int.

The way to solve this is to pass in a String representation of your number.

```
num1 = new BigDecimal("123123123123123123123123");
```

Answer (score 0):

num1 = new BigDecimal(**2147483648l**);
num2 = new BigDecimal(**2147483649l**);

BigDecimal constructor supports long/double as parameter, use one of these.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers are are always interpreted as ints. if you want the number to be compiled as long, you should add the suffix "L" to it, so it will be `2147483647333L`. In case for numbers bigger than MAX_LONG (~2^31) you should provide them as byte arrays using [this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29) with the string representation of the number ("1234.56").

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to create the BigDecimal (or BigInteger) with a larger number? If so, first thing you should do is append an `L` to your number literal -- that makes it a `long` instead of an `int`. If that's not big enough, you can also create new BigDecimals/BigIntegers by passing them a `String` representation of the number.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the constructor that **accepts the value as String** otherwise you are limited by the size of the data type you are using, to avoid which you wanted to use BigXXXX classes.

Answer (score 0):

BigDecimal will take a long in the constructor.  But you will need an L at the end.

new BigDecimal(2147483648L) should work.