# how to add two big numbers in java

Tags: java, math

I want to add two numbers in java:76561197960265728 and 96279315.
I tried with Big Integer but it didn't work ;/
POC:

```
BigInteger big = new BigInteger("96279315");
BigInteger bigg = new BigInteger("76561197960265728");
bigg.add(big);
System.out.println(bigg);
```

In PHP i can do:

```
echo bcadd(96279315, '76561197960265728');
```

and it works well.

How to (easy) do it in java?
Thanks

Comment: Please make SOME research effort before asking. Just searching `biginteger.add` or even `how to add biginteger in java` pulls up a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783912/java-how-to-use-biginteger), a [related question which is very nearly a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748846/how-to-add-two-numbers-of-any-length-in-java), a nice [tutorial which shows you how to use it](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/biginteger_add.htm) and even [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add(java.math.BigInteger)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`add` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add-java.math.BigInteger-) doesn't modify the object; it returns a new `BigInteger` representing the sum.

Assign the returned value back to `bigg`.

Comment: I was bemused... Thanks :))

Comment: As the asker of this question, you may [accept exactly one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark next to the answer that you think is the best.

Answer (score 1):

**BigInteger** (and BigDecimal too) is unlike any other Numerical object in Java **inmutable**. This means that you cannot change that state of the object after it was created. This is adventagous for many reasons, but has a serious drawback:

You are getting new Objects after each operation, which you need assign:
So instead of a simple:

```
a.add(b);
```

You need to do:

```
result = a.add(b);
```

Or if you can save a new variable declaration by reusing a:

```
a = a.add(b);
```