# Adding Byte Arrays of unlimited size in Java

Tags: java, math, arrays, operations

Is there a simple way how to make byte arrays adding?

**I mean a mathematical adding (no concatenation):**

```
00 00 FF    
00 00 FF
--------
00 01 FE
```

I can achieve that by converting the byte array to a numeric format, but this approach is limited by max value of the number format. I need a solution that can work with much larger values than standard formats provide.

Comment: Show us your attempt

Comment: Have you tried BigInteger?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add two numbers of any length in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748846/how-to-add-two-numbers-of-any-length-in-java)

Comment: You know how long addition works, you've learned this in elementary school. It's a different base and there's a funny thing when you have to carry past the end of the array, but you can do it I'm sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28byte[]%29) which has no theoretical limit to it's size. In practice, obviously, if the number of bytes is too big to fit in memory than you need to take a different approach.

```
public void test() {
    BigInteger a = new BigInteger(new byte[]{(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xff});
    BigInteger b = new BigInteger(new byte[]{(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xff});

    System.out.println(a.toString(16) + "+" + b.toString(16) + "=" + a.add(b).toString(16));
}
```

prints `ff+ff=1fe`.