# How to assign very large numbers to variable in java?

Tags: java

I'm getting "integer number too large: 1000000000001" for the following code line.  How do I make it so that maxValue can hold 1 quadrillion or 1 trillion?

```
long maxValue = 1000000000001;      //1,000,000,000,001
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to use a long literal (with an `L` at the end):

```
long maxValue = 1000000000001L; //1,000,000,000,001
```

Note that you don't need to use BigInteger if your numbers are between -2<sup>63</sup> and 2<sup>63</sup>-1 (inclusive). (2<sup>63</sup>-1 = 9223372036854775807L = 0x7fffffffffffffffL.)

Comment: Actually `2^63` = 9 223 372 036 854 775 808 (10) = 8000000000000000 (16). Max value is `2^63 - 1` (because of two's complement binary representation).

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8924925/6444297) is complete.

[Java Language Specification:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10)

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII
>   letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).

Answer (score 0):

You may check for another question and answer before you ask. Someone probably has the same question and got the best answer. See this:

[Large Numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849813/large-numbers-in-java)

This is probably what you need.

Comment: The question you linked to had as solution to use BigInteger. That's not needed in this case.