# Java long number too large error?

Tags: java

Why do I get an int number is too large where the long is assigned to min and max?

```
/*
long: The long data type is a 64-bit signed two's complement integer.
It has a minimum value of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and a maximum value of         9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive).
Use this data type when you need a range of values wider than those provided by int.
*/
package Literals;

public class Literal_Long {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        long a = 1;
        long b = 2;
        long min = -9223372036854775808;
        long max = 9223372036854775807;//Inclusive

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(a + b);
        System.out.println(min);
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Long.MIN_VALUE` and `Long.MAX_VALUE` or `1L << -1` and `-1L >>> 1`

Answer (score 77, accepted):

All literal numbers in java are by default `ints`, which has range `-2147483648` to  `2147483647` inclusive.

Your literals are outside this range, so to make this compile you need to indicate they're `long` literals (ie suffix with `L`):

```
long min = -9223372036854775808L;
long max = 9223372036854775807L;
```

Note that java supports both uppercase `L` and lowercase `l`, but I recommend **not** using lowercase `l` because it looks like a `1`:

```
long min = -9223372036854775808l; // confusing: looks like the last digit is a 1
long max = 9223372036854775807l; // confusing: looks like the last digit is a 1
```

[Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10) for the same

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).

Comment: To be pedantic: You could also use a small `l`.

Comment: @OliverWeiler I'd say, to be pedantic, you could **but shouldn't** use a small __l__ 'cause it looks like a __1__.

Comment: It only looks like a 1 if you use a bad font, but sure, why risk the confusion.

Answer (score 25):

You must use `L` to say to the compiler that it is a long literal.

```
long min = -9223372036854775808L;
long max = 9223372036854775807L;//Inclusive
```