# How can I pass number greater than 999 999 999 as parameter in java

Tags: java

Can I pass number greater than 999 999 999 as parameter in java.

When I do like this it gives compiler error the literal 999 999 999 9 of type is out of range

```
 passNumber(9999999999);

 public String passNumber(long number){
     if(number > 999999999)
         throw new BigNumberException("Number too large")
 }
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924896/java-long-number-too-large-error) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769963/javas-l-number-long-specification-question) questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because 9,999,999,999 is considered as an `int` by the compiler and is larger than [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) (2,147,483,647).

You can use a `long`: `9999999999L`.

Answer (score 7):

Use `9999999999L` to tell the compiler it's a long literal, and not an int literal.

Answer (score 4):

That's because 9 billion is out of integer range (signed int up to 2,147,483,647 and unsigned int up to 4,294,967,295).

Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29) to learn more.