# Integer too long Java

Tags: java

```
  public static void gramstoAtoms()
  {
   System.out.println("Enter Amount of grams");
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   long x = keyboard.nextLong();
   System.out.println("Enter Unit Grams");
   long y = keyboard.nextLong();
   long result = x/y;
   long answer = result*60200000000000000000000;
   System.out.println(answer + "Atoms");
  }
```

How do I change this code so that I don't get an integer is too long error?

Comment: Use a BigInteger, of course.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924896/java-long-number-too-large-error

Comment: Use Big integer :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783912/java-how-to-use-biginteger

Comment: Or BigDecimal, given that your division should probably be not be an integer division. Multiplying a truncation error by such a large number will give a totally incorrect response

Comment: DuffyMO is correct, as usual :)

Comment: If you don't need a very precise answer a `double` is more suitable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just use BigInteger instead of long

```
BigInteger bi=new BigInteger("6020000000000000000000");
```

for your method:

```
public static void gramstoAtoms()
  {
   System.out.println("Enter Amount of grams");
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   String x = keyboard.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter Unit Grams");
   String y = keyboard.nextLine();
   BigInteger result = new BigInteger(x).divide(new BigInteger(y));
   BigInteger answer = result.multiply(new BigInteger("60200000000000000000000"));
   System.out.println(answer + "Atoms");
  }
```

and if your `x` and `y` are small, you can use them with simple long, but when multiply by the 602.......0000 use the `BigInteger`

Comment: what do i need to import for the class, because it gives me this:

Comment: import java.math.BigInteger;

Comment: It compiles, however it does not multiply the result

Comment: my output: Enter Amount of grams
5
Enter Unit Grams
2
120400000000000000000000Atoms

Comment: Try gram = 45 and unit gram = 23

Comment: Grams = 6 and unit gram = 7 gives me 0 too

Comment: this is because this is integers and not doubles, try first multiply by the big number and then divide it, because 45/23 gives 1.9 ant it takes the floor of it

Comment: Thank you so much, this code works very well now.

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly, Avogadro's number is `6.02e24`.  A `long` has a max value of `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`, which isn't big enough.  You'll need `BigInteger`.

Comment: How do I put in BigInteger into the code, it gives me a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

It's a solution without `BigInteger`:

```
long answer = result * 602;
System.out.println(answer + "00000000000000000000Atoms");
```

Comment: I was about to write this. If you always expect to have so many zeros at the end, why bother handling such big numbers?

Comment: @MMM The question *expects* to have so many zeros, according to the code he provides. I still use `BigInteger` when necessary.

Comment: That's what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

Dima Goltsman is correct, you had to fix it using the BigInteger