# A big integer input in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Large Numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849813/large-numbers-in-java)

I need to take and manipulate an integer input with <= 500 digits. How can it be done in java? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class is a good place to start for big ints.

I'll have to check the documentation to see what the upper bound on `BigInteger` is, but it should suit your needs.

Comment: No, actually the input data constraint is <=500 digit. My program works fine as long as it is within the limits of a long, but beyond that, I didn't know what to do.

Comment: Gotcha.  :)  Sorry, it just seemed odd to give an upper bound instead of a lower bound when talking about big numbers I guess.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class BigIntegerExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       BigInteger bigInteger1 = new BigInteger ("123456789");
       BigInteger bigInteger2 = new BigInteger ("112334");
       BigInteger bigIntResult = bigInteger1.multiply(bigInteger2); 
       System.out.println("Result is  ==> " + bigIntResult);
    }
}
```

You can take as long value in integer using Biginteger class.

Comment: Take more care with your indentation please, Abhishekkumar.

Comment: Thanks sir i will keep in mind this thing in future.