# how to assign huge value variable

Tags: java, variables, digits

it is possible to assign that big number in java? i need to make a calculation of 39 digits value. could any help? Thanks

Problem:
Consider the following composite number:
340282367237851113557325445936183246849
Write a Java method to find two numbers whose product is the above number.

Comment: Looks like a homework assignment or interview question. Why not first try to solve this yourself and show us your attempt?

Comment: Yes, there are several ways to do that.  A quick google search should give you most or all of them.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: To point you in the correct direction read on BigDecimal or on BigInteger....

Comment: Here is the answer for your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849813/large-numbers-in-java

Answer (score 4):

I guess you need to check out the `BigInteger` of the java API. That might be able to store your results of those much big numbers. Read the documentation,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html