# how to store really big numbers to use in calculations?

Tags: java

How can I store a number in java that doesn't fit in integer neither in long .

I am trying to find the numbers divisible by 3 between one and a certain                                                                                               number but the problem says that this number is so big that it cannot be stored in an `int` nor a `long`.

Basically I am not allowed to store it in an `int` nor  a `long` so were should i store it?

Comment: java.math.BigInteger

Comment: And java.math.BigDecimal for non-integers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Large Numbers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849813/large-numbers-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Use [java.math.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) that provides arbitrary long integers and methods to operate on them.