# What datatype to use for 40 digit integers in java

Tags: java, integer-overflow

For example

first number = 123456.....40 digits
second number = 123456.....40digits

Then I need to store the number

```
third = first * second;
```

after that I need to print third and again I need to perform operation like

```
fourth = third * third;
```

and print fourth. So how can I handle that much long integers which data type I need to use?

Comment: A 40 bit integer does not have 40 digits, it has 13 (`2^40`).

Comment: [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)?

Comment: Hi Tim sorry its not 40 bit it is 40 digit integer

Comment: hi gauravmahawar actually I am using a recursive function where I am using long so after some time its returning me some 22 digits number but long data type can't handle that much data so I want to know how to handle it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/849813/4185106

Comment: You can't. The max value of `Long` is `2^63 - 1` ie `9223372036854775807 ` which has 19 digits. You want to handle numbers higher than that, use `BigInteger`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BigInteger` class in `java.math`, then use `BigInteger.multiply` to multiply them together.

Check here for more on how to use it:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/biginteger_multiply.htm

Comment: Or better, look at existing questions/answers on StackOverflow: [Large Numbers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849813/large-numbers-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

See this question its similar [Arbitrary-precision arithmetic Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218149/arbitrary-precision-arithmetic-explanation)
the answer explain it quite good.

The basic is that you work with smaller parts. Just remember how you learned to work with big numbers in school (2-3 grade) you wrote down two numbers and

```
 2351
  *12
 -----
 4702
2351
------
28212
```

You just do small operations and store them somewhere you can put them in string or better in some array of integers. Where for example

number 123456789123456789 can be
number[0] = 6789
number[1] = 2345
number[3] = 7891
number[4] = 2345
number[5] = 1
String numberToShow = "";
for(int i = 0; i

There are some links for computer arighmetics
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Computer_arithmetic
and for adders
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Adders_(electronics)

In your computer you have basically also just some adders which can work only with some size of numbers and if you need to work with bigger you need to split it in smaller parts. 
Some of this parts can be done parallel, so you can speed up your algorithm. These are usually more sophisticated.
But the basic principe is similar to working with big numbers on your primary school.