# why i multiply many number make a mistake when i division?

Tags: java, algorithm, division

This is my result:

2 x 3 x 5 x 7 x 11 x 13 x 17 x 19 x 23 x 29 x 31 x 37 x 41 x 43 x 47 x 53 x 59 x 61 = 3,982,538,761,641,808,742

divisable 2 : true
divisable 3 : false
divisable 5 : false
divisable 7 : false
divisable 11 : true

this is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ArrayList<Long> prime = prime();
    System.out.println("size : " + prime.size());

    long i = 1;
    for (Long l : prime) {
        System.out.print(" x "+l);
        i *= l;
    }
    System.out.println(" = "+i);
    long a[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11};
    for (long b : a) {
        System.out.printf("divisable %d : %b %n", b, i % b == 0 ? true : false);
    }
}

public static ArrayList<Long> prime() {
    ArrayList<Long> res = new ArrayList<>();
    res.add(new Long(2));

    next:
    for (long i = 3; i < Byte.MAX_VALUE / 2; i += 2) {
        //make Byte.MAX_VALUE / 3 will return true;
        for (Long l : res) {
            boolean b = true;
            if (i % l == 0) {
                continue next;
            }
        }

        res.add(i);

    }

    return res;
}
```

Can anyone please explain why is that? Thank you :)

Comment: can you please post the code??

Comment: Probably wrong data type. (Show some code for more detailed help.)

Comment: i just multiply like : 2 x 3 x 5 x 7 x 11 x 13 x 17 x 19 x 23 x 29 x 31 x 37 x 41 x 43 x 47 x 53 x 59 x 61

Comment: Before you update: don't post code in comments. Update your question instead.

Comment: Try using `BigInteger` to get rid of the capacity issues.

Comment: Short answer: integer overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to wolfram alpha, the result is

```
117288381359406970983270
```

However in java the largest number an int can store is

```
2147483647
```

And even a long integer, which is 64 bits can only hold

```
9223372036854775807
```

To get around this, you will need to use some form of big number class. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849813/large-numbers-in-java) for some ways of doing so.

To summarise that linked question, you can use the big integer class from java.math to get around this:

```
BigInteger result = new BigInteger("117288381359406970983270");
```

It also includes functions to add and multiply BigIntegers.

Comment: what about speed of BigInteger ? How does it works ? :p

Comment: Yes, using BigInteger will be slower than using regular data types, but there is no way to avoid it using numbers that big. To make a BigInteger, use the syntax in my example. For multiplication, you can use the BigInteger.multiply() method, which takes another BigInteger as an argument, and returns the products as a BigInteger.

Comment: @ThangPhung You have to pay some price.

Answer (score 1):

You're possibly taking wrong data type to store result because

```
2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19 * 23 * 29 * 31 * 37 * 41 * 43 * 47 * 53 * 59 * 61
=117288381359406970983270
```

You can switch to BigIntegers in Java

Here's a working java code:

**Output**

```
117288381359406970983270
Divisible by 2 : true
Divisible by 3 : true
Divisible by 5 : true
Divisible by 7 : true
Divisible by 11 : true
```

**Code**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {2,  3,  5,  7,  11,  13,  17,  19,  23,  29,  31,  37,  41,  43,  47,  53,  59,  61};

        BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("1");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            bi = bi.multiply(new BigInteger(Integer.toString(arr[i])));
        }

        System.out.println(bi);

        System.out.println("Divisible by 2 : " + bi.mod(new BigInteger("2")).toString().equals("0"));
        System.out.println("Divisible by 3 : " + bi.mod(new BigInteger("3")).toString().equals("0"));
        System.out.println("Divisible by 5 : " + bi.mod(new BigInteger("5")).toString().equals("0"));
        System.out.println("Divisible by 7 : " + bi.mod(new BigInteger("7")).toString().equals("0"));
        System.out.println("Divisible by 11 : " + bi.mod(new BigInteger("11")).toString().equals("0"));
    }
}
```

Comment: what about speed of BigInteger ? How does it works ? :p

Comment: @ThangPhung obviously it's slow then primitive data types. But this is what you need if you are operating on numbers that large.

Answer (score 0):

Because 3982538761641808742 - is wrong result.
Because long type is not long enough to store right result.

Comment: But why did that result happen? Write a useful response

Comment: Because `long` type is not long enough to store right result.

Comment: Well then put that in your answer. Don't just give a simple solution with no explanation.

Comment: @ThangPhung, no the value is too big. What you get is the wrong result due to overflow.

Answer (score -1):

this result: 3982538761641808742 is depending of what are this values for a type:

> 2 x 3 x 5 x 7 x 11 x 13 x 17 x 19 x 23 x 29 x 31 x 37 x 41 x 43 x 47 x 53 x 59 x 61

if those are ints then you get an overflow since the result can not be hold in 32 bits and is not even close to **3982538761641808742** ...

if you define those as a long operation then

*3982538761641808742* is the result of

```
final long n0 = 2L * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19 * 23 * 29 * 31 * 37 * 41 * 43 * 47 * 53 * 59 * 61;
```

no matter what, 3982538761641808742

- divided by 2 in not resulting an int so divisable 2 : true
- divided by 2 in not resulting an int so divisable 3 : false
- divided by 2 in not resulting an int so divisable 5 : false
- divided by 2 in not resulting an int so divisable 7 : false
- divided by 2 in not resulting an int so divisable 11 : true

which is correct...