# How to deal with floating point number approximation?

Tags: delphi, floating-point, floating-accuracy, delphi-2007

I have a `TDBEdit` connected to a `TFloatField` which has `DisplayFormat = '0.################'`.
I've set the field's value to `12.123456789` and I've noticed that my edit control displays it as `'12,1234567890000005'`.

[image]

I don't have a deep knowledge about floating point numbers but I know that this happens because floating point numbers are approximated.

Anyhow, I'm wondering how can I make sure that additional decimals will never "magically" appear after the user types a value?

I thought to shorten the `DisplayFormat` string by removing one `'#'` but I don't know if this would be sufficient to avoid the problem in any condition.

**Example:**

```
uses
  DBClient, DB, DBCtrls;

...

var
  Dst : TClientDataSet;
  Dsc : TDataSource;
  Fld : TFloatField;
  Edit : TDBEdit;
begin
  //components creation
  Dst := TClientDataSet.Create(Application);
  Dst.FieldDefs.Add('TEST', ftFloat, 0, False);
  Dst.CreateDataSet();

  Fld := Dst.Fields[0] as TFloatField;
  Fld.DisplayFormat := '0.################';

  Dsc := TDataSource.Create(Application);
  Dsc.DataSet := Dst;

  Edit := TDBEdit.Create(Application);
  Edit.DataSource := Dsc;
  Edit.DataField := Fld.FieldName;
  Edit.Align := alTop;
  Edit.Parent := Self;

  //test
  Dst.Open();
  Dst.Append();
  Fld.AsFloat := 12.123456789;
  Dst.Post();
```

Comment: You can't avoid this, it's inherent with binary floating point. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken  What you can do is use a decimal real data type instead of a binary real data type. In Delphi that would typically mean `Currency` although it's a bit limited. You might be better therefore with a third party decimal real data type.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, you can do better. Python 3.1 introduced a change in the way `repr` works for floating point values, so that it produces the shortest string which represents the actual value. Details here: https://bugs.python.org/issue1580  But there's nothing like that implemented in standard Delphi libraries.

Comment: You can also use `ftFMTBCD` as field type. The corresponding field should be of type `TFMTBCDField` then. This field type has less restrictions than `ftBCD` - although also less performance..

Comment: "how can I make sure that additional decimals will never "magically" appear " --> As most FP use a binary base, insure the  only decimal values used are also binary representable ones like 12.5, 12.0625, 12.0015411376953125, ...

Comment: @chux impractical

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Ok but isn't there a number of decimals which a [Double](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Double) data type can represent without accuracy problems?

Comment: @Fabrizio, I think you must accept the inaccuracies of binary floating point. To estimate the accuracy, see [How accurate is “double-precision floating-point format”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43836678/576719)

Comment: @Fabrizio It's more complicated. You followed the link I gave you right?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I understand that accuracy problem is unavoidable but I just want to hide these problems to the user

Comment: Never mind. I don't have a magic solution for you, and our communication doesn't seem to be working properly.