# How to get the Fibonacci of numbers like 8181?

Tags: java, algorithm

the result of the code below is : 3877337276612781506
but i tried online Fibonacci calculator and got huge number of more than 1000 decimals

in such numbers how can i got the Fibonacci result?

```
Long fnOfZero = 0L, fnOfOne = 1L, n, i, count = 8182L;
for (i = 2L; i < count; ++i){
  n = fnOfZero + fnOfOne;
  System.out.print(i + ":  ");
  System.out.println(n));
  fnOfZero = fnOfOne;
  fnOfOne = n;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "the Fibonacci of numbers like 8181"? Fibonacci numbers are a sequence, not a function.

Comment: fibonacci of big numbers like 8181

Comment: You didn't go look at how many bytes can be stored in a long. It sits at 8 bytes with a range of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 
9,223,372,036,854,775,807. Your number cannot go higher because it's limited by the datatype

Comment: this is the function of fibonacci: `f{n}=f_{{n-1}} + f_{{n-2}}`

Comment: If you use a biginteger instead of a long you will be able to store 100 digits whereas a long can only store 19

Comment: If you want a `double` estimation: `Math.pow((1 + Math.sqrt(5))/2, n) / Math.sqrt(5)`; if value is too big for `double` you can work with *logarithms*.

Comment: even BigInteger can not store the result !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Large Numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849813/large-numbers-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    BigInteger secondLast = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger last = BigInteger.ONE;
    int count = 8182;
    for (int i = 2; i < count; ++i) {
        BigInteger n = secondLast.add(last);
        secondLast = last;
        last = n;
    }
    System.out.println(last);
```

It prints a number with 1710 digits in it.

I used your algorithm and just substituted `BigInteger` for `Long` as already said in the comment.

Answer (score -1):

You may give Big Decimal a try.