# My Integer Overflow how to carry more digites

Tags: java, variables, long-integer

How to carry this number

```
119622220865480194561963161495657715064383733760000000000
```

in a variable?

Comment: `String number = "119622220865480194561963161495657715064383733760000000000";`.

Comment: `new BigInteger("119622220865480194561963161495657715064383733760000000000");`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Large Numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849813/large-numbers-in-java)

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow before posting.