# My code is not producing the correct output

Tags: java, loops, factorial

```
 long fact= 1;
 for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
     fact=fact*i;
 }
 System.out.println(fact);
```

The code should produce factorial of large numbers, for example 25. But the output is not correct.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit the headline to something that describes your problem better? As it stands, it's rather generic.

Comment: Does it output anything at all? or it's stuck? give us specific example, and we can help you better.

Comment: what is n here?

Comment: 25! will be in the order of 10^27 = 10^(3*9) = 2^(10*9) = 90 bits. So it exceeds a long. Use `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 3):

Like Samir Vyas said
"It exceeds the number range which can be represented by java long type."
If you want to bypass this limit, you will need to use a `BigInteger` or a `BigDecimal`.
You can find more information on this question [Large Numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849813/large-numbers-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

It exceeds the number range which can be represented by java `long` type.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
int n = 30;                                
System.out.printf("%d! = %,d%n",n,fact(n));

public static BigInteger fact(int fact) {        
    BigInteger f = BigInteger.valueOf(fact);     
    while (--fact > 1) {                         
        f = f.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(fact));
    }                                            
    return f;                                    
}
```

Prints

```
30! = 265,252,859,812,191,058,636,308,480,000,000
```

For more information on arbitrary precision math check out [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) and [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) in the JDK API.